# CloudTable.Execute not working in API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, reference, azure-storage

I just moved a function from an MVC App to an MVC API App, and for some reason it all works except `CloudTable.Execute`.

Code:

```
try
            {
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
        "accountName",
        "key"), true);

                CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
                CloudTable table = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference("SkypeUsers");
                table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<WorkUser>("Skype", skypeid);
                TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation); //Does not work

                retrievedSkypeId = ((WorkUser)retrievedResult.Result).RowKey;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Error:

```
Error CS1061 'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no 
extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudTable' could 
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage is the same version I use in my App. Ive tried cleaning and re-building. Not sure what the issue is.

EDIT:

Print of my only Execute-options:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error CS1061 'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[CloudTable.Execute Method (TableOperation, TableRequestOptions, OperationContext)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.execute.aspx) accepts a **TableOperation** object as the first argument, and according to the code you provide, we could find you indeed pass a TableOperation object to **Execute** method, it should not return the error. Please try to install the latest version [Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) to your project (the code works fine with WindowsAzure.Storage  v8.0.0 on my side) and test if same issue will appear. You could also tell us the version of WindowsAzure.Storage you are using now, and then we will test the code with that version.

Besides, please try to use **TableQuery** to generate a query and call CloudTable.ExecuteQuery method to retrieve the entity.

```
TableQuery<WorkUser> query = new TableQuery<WorkUser>().Where(
    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Skype"),
        TableOperators.And,
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, skypeid)));

retrievedSkypeId = table.ExecuteQuery(query).FirstOrDefault().RowKey;
```

Comment: I have the same issue with WindowsAzure.Storage 8.4.0 on ASP.NET Core 2.0

Answer (score 6):

I am targeting .NET Core & using assembly `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.2.0.0`.
The `ExecuteQuery` does not exist within `CloudTable` for this version.
This might be your case as well.

Use:

```
table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null).Result;
```

The ExecuteQuery sync is still available for .NET Framework version however for NET Standard use ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync instead.

Comment: While this line of code might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.

Comment: It might be good to note that in general case, you might need to iterate execution as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234350/how-to-execute-an-azure-table-storage-query-async-client-version-4-0-1

Comment: Great answer.. Documentation is all for older version. But never use .Result.. instead use await table.ExecureQuerySegmentedAsync